# WinCE 6.0 Reading ini files

Tags: visual-c++, windows-ce

This might be a philosophical qustion, but I am reviewing code by a previous engineer and was wondering when the best time was to read the ini file.  The current application re-reads the ini file each time it needs a value and writes data each time it changes.  A better solution in my mind would be to read/write it once and store the information in memory.  Am I missing something?  There is about 40 entries in the ini file.

Also the engineer made his own class, isn't there an existing class to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, I would read the configuration once on startup and I'd do that not only on CE but on any other system, too. If I want to be able to react to changes in the configuration, I'd prefer reloading to be explicit, like e.g. sending the program a signal. Lacking signals under CE, you could use a named event or ask the user if you have a UI. Lacking all that, I'd check the timestamp of the file in regular intervals and reload the file on changes, but still keep a copy in memory.

The reason to not open-read-close a file for single values is that sometimes two values have dependencies, and if you do that you could get an old and a new value into memory, leading to inconsistencies. Also, I'd validate the configuration for sanity before actually starting to use it. That said, it is also horribly inefficient to access the hard disk just to read a single configuration value.

Concerning the writing of changes, I'd do that either on explicit request by the user or automatically after accepting changes. Still, I'd try to avoid writing single value for the same reason as not reading single values.

Lastly, INI files have been declared as obsolete, so the win32 API for reading and writing them is not supported by CE. This explains why someone rolls their own classes to read and write these files. MS want you to use the registry instead, for which the API is present and supported. I don't really agree with MS here, since textual configuration files (not necessary INI files) provide some features that the registry doesn't, like e.g. the ability to use existing text tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) library to read and write INI-files.

Here is the sample code that reads an INI file, modifies and saves it back:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

/*
[owner]
name=John Doe
organization=Acme Widgets Inc.
*/

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;

    // Read
    read_ini("data.ini", pt);
    std::cout << pt.get<std::string>("owner.name") << std::endl; // John Doe
    std::cout << pt.get<std::string>("owner.organization") << std::endl; // Acme Widgets Inc.

    // Write
    pt.put<std::string>("owner.name", "New Name");
    pt.put<std::string>("owner.name", "New Organization");
    write_ini("date2.ini", pt);

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** When compiling this code on Windows CE you might need to the adjust the Boost.PropertyTree library. It seems that Standard C++ Library for Windows CE doesn't have `<locale>` header and Boost.PropertyTree uses it when reading and writing INI-files.

Comment: In order to get the <locale> header, you could also switch to STLport, which supports CE5 and 6 (and to some extent even earlier versions).